# Test case failed in hackerRank

Tags: python

Can any one help me out?
Given an array of integers, calculate the ratios of its elements that are positive, negative, and zero. Print the decimal value of each fraction on a new line with 6  places after the decimal.
Here is link----> (https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/plus-minus/problem?isFullScreen=true&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen)

```
def plusMinus(arr):
    # Write your code her
    a  = 0
    b = 0
    c = 0
    pos, neg, zer = 0,0,0
    for i in arr:
        if (i >= 1):
            a +=1
            pos = a / len(arr)  
        if (i <= -1):
            b+=1
            neg = b/len(arr)
        if (i==0):
            c+=1
            zer = c/len(arr) 
    
    return(f'{pos:.6f}\n{neg:.6f}\n{zer:.6f}')
arr = [-4,3,-9,0,4,1]
plusMinus(arr)
print(plusMinus(arr))
```

Comment: Can you link the problem? The question is not very clear

Comment: I've come up with this solution : 

```
    def plusMinus(arr):
    # Write your code here
    a  = 0
    b = 0
    c = 0
    pos, neg, zer = 0,0,0
    for i in arr:
        if (i > 0):
            a +=1
        if (i < 0):
            b+=1
        if (i==0):
            c+=1
    a = a/len(arr)
    b = b/len(arr)
    c = c/len(arr)
    return(f'{a:.6f}\n{b:.6f}\n{c:.6f}')
``` 
I'll delete the comment when I'm able to post the answer

Answer (score 1):

Don't delete the code that is on the website when the challenge starts

In your case, the starting code looks like this:

```
#!/bin/python3

import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys

#
# Complete the 'plusMinus' function below.
#
# The function accepts INTEGER_ARRAY arr as parameter.
#

def plusMinus(arr):
    # Write your code here

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input().strip())

    arr = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))

    plusMinus(arr)
```

note the `# Write your code here`, don't alter the other parts of the code as they are needed to make the testcases work.

Simpyly pasting your code of the function to the correct place and making it actually print itself will give full points:

```
#!/bin/python3

import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys

#
# Complete the 'plusMinus' function below.
#
# The function accepts INTEGER_ARRAY arr as parameter.
#

def plusMinus(arr):
    # Write your code her
    a  = 0
    b = 0
    c = 0
    pos, neg, zer = 0,0,0
    for i in arr:
        if (i >= 1):
            a +=1
            pos = a / len(arr)  
        if (i <= -1):
            b+=1
            neg = b/len(arr)
        if (i==0):
            c+=1
            zer = c/len(arr) 
    
    print(f'{pos:.6f}\n{neg:.6f}\n{zer:.6f}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input().strip())

    arr = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))

    plusMinus(arr)
```

brings the desired output

Answer (score 0):

The function should not return the value. It should print the value in each line. Change your return to print

```
print(f'{pos:.6f}\n{neg:.6f}\n{zer:.6f}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, just did not satisfy the question itself, which states: **Print the decimal value of each ...**
You used return, which by definition passes that correct output out into the global code, but it never gets printed, thus the test cases are failing.